# cordova / ios / hybrid app - UITableView loads items incorrectly and out of order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cordova, delegates

I am getting peculiar behavior from my `UITableView`. It is loading rows `0, 1, 2` - but when it gets to row `3`, it loads row `4` instead, and then for row `4`, it loads row `0` again, so it is like this:

Rows in table:

```
0
1
2
4
0
```

It obviously should go `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` in order. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: %li", indexPath.row);

    [self.items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"items at every cell entry: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"item"]);
    }];

    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %li, %@", (long)indexPath.row, [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    PoolsTableViewCell *cell = (PoolsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell.cellLeftImageView.image == nil) {

        NSInteger left = 2*indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"left: %li", (long)left);

        NSObject* obj = (NSObject*)[self.items objectAtIndex:left];

        cell.cellLeftViewLabel.text = [obj valueForKey:@"item"];

        NSString *ImageURL = [obj valueForKey:@"downloadURL"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
        cell.cellLeftImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        NSInteger right = (2*indexPath.row)+1;
        NSLog(@"right: %li", (long)right);

        if(right < [self.items count]) {
            NSLog(@"inside right < self.items count conditional");
            NSObject* objPlus = (NSObject*)[self.items objectAtIndex:right];

            cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = [objPlus valueForKey:@"item"];

            NSString *secondImageURL = [objPlus valueForKey:@"downloadURL"];
            NSData *secondImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondImageURL]];
            cell.cellRightImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:secondImageData];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I have this code which logs all of the items each time `cellForRowAtIndex` is called:

```
[self.items enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, 
    BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"items at every cell entry: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"item"]);
}];
```

I am loading 2 items from `self.items` into each row (each row has 2 columns, essentially). The console output is correct for each call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - so `self.items` should never be referenced out of order, but it is - this is an example of my console output when the `UITableView` loads:

```
2019-02-02 22:01:30.121975-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 0
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122149-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Table
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122263-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Cord
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122373-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Keys
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122645-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122769-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-02 22:01:30.122947-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Book
2019-02-02 22:01:30.123054-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Njhhnn
2019-02-02 22:01:30.123160-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Tv
2019-02-02 22:01:30.123260-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: 9th item
2019-02-02 22:01:30.129478-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] left: 0
2019-02-02 22:01:31.024184-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] right: 1
2019-02-02 22:01:31.024302-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] inside right < self.items count conditional
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719052-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 1
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719252-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Table
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719374-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Cord
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719481-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Keys
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719584-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719687-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719785-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Book
2019-02-02 22:01:31.719884-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Njhhnn
2019-02-02 22:01:31.720048-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Tv
2019-02-02 22:01:31.720170-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: 9th item
2019-02-02 22:01:31.724875-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] left: 2
2019-02-02 22:01:32.340747-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] right: 3
2019-02-02 22:01:32.340969-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] inside right < self.items count conditional
2019-02-02 22:01:32.776360-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 2
2019-02-02 22:01:32.776572-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Table
2019-02-02 22:01:32.776685-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Cord
2019-02-02 22:01:32.776877-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Keys
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777113-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777244-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777344-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Book
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777443-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Njhhnn
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777542-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Tv
2019-02-02 22:01:32.777641-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: 9th item
2019-02-02 22:01:32.782148-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] left: 4
2019-02-02 22:01:33.383439-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] right: 5
2019-02-02 22:01:33.383649-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] inside right < self.items count conditional
2019-02-02 22:01:34.534761-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 3
2019-02-02 22:01:34.534980-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Table
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535099-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Cord
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535206-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Keys
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535310-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535412-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535666-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Book
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535787-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Njhhnn
2019-02-02 22:01:34.535895-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Tv
2019-02-02 22:01:34.536022-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: 9th item
2019-02-02 22:01:34.540261-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] left: 6
2019-02-02 22:01:35.090979-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] right: 7
2019-02-02 22:01:35.091111-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] inside right < self.items count conditional
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886101-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 4
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886329-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Table
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886446-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Cord
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886554-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Keys
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886658-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-02 22:01:35.886978-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-02 22:01:35.887082-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Book
2019-02-02 22:01:35.887184-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Njhhnn
2019-02-02 22:01:35.887311-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: Tv
2019-02-02 22:01:35.887449-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] items at ever cell entry: 9th item
2019-02-02 22:01:35.891688-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] left: 8
2019-02-02 22:01:36.660758-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] right: 9
2019-02-02 22:01:36.931630-0500 HybridPool[1720:534623] Item added! pool
```

To clarify for the names of items in `self.items` that I see presented in the table goes like this:

```
**Row 0:**
Table, Cord
**Row 1:**
Keys, Hshhdhdbd
**Row 2:**
Jhghhvhh, Book
**Row 3:**
9th item, (blank - because there are only 9 items - not an even 10) --> this row should be last!
**Row 4:**
Table, Cord <- this is the first row again, this should be what is in **Row 3** - 9th item, blank.
```

I should also show this just incase there is something I am doing wrong here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if([self.items count] % 2 != 0) {
        return ([self.items count] + 1) / 2;
    }
    else {
        return [self.items count] / 2;
    }
}
```

For above, because I am loading two items into the row, I handle the case when there are an even amount of items (which is just dividing `[self.items count]` by `2`. For an odd amount of `self.items`, I add `1` before dividing by `2` so that there is a row available for the last item (and then a spot in that row is left blank). This seems correct to me, but maybe I am missing some tricky bug here?

Judging from the console output I don't know why the rows are being loaded out of order, or why `Row 0` repeats for `Row 4`, please help, thanks!

**UPDATE**

Getting the same result with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: %li", indexPath.row);

    [self.leftItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"leftItem: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"item"]);
    }];

    [self.rightItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"rightItem: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"item"]);
    }];

    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //NSLog(@"indexPath.row: %li, %@", (long)indexPath.row, [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    PoolsTableViewCell *cell = (PoolsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell.cellLeftImageView.image == nil) { //Equivalent to cell == nil
        NSObject* leftObj = [self.leftItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSObject* rightObj = [self.rightItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.cellLeftViewLabel.text = [leftObj valueForKey:@"item"];

        NSString *ImageURL = [leftObj valueForKey:@"downloadURL"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
        cell.cellLeftImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        if(![rightObj isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = [rightObj valueForKey:@"item"];

            NSString *secondImageURL = [rightObj valueForKey:@"downloadURL"];
            NSData *secondImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondImageURL]];
            cell.cellRightImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:secondImageData];
        }
        else {
            cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = @"";
            cell.cellRightImageView.image = nil;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**console output:**

```
2019-02-03 11:32:50.583214-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 0
2019-02-03 11:32:50.583377-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:32:50.583486-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:32:50.583605-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:32:50.583997-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584116-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584224-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584328-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584429-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584528-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:32:50.584771-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647304-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 1
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647551-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647666-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647773-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647876-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:32:54.647992-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:32:54.648102-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:32:54.648199-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:32:54.648403-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:32:54.648519-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:32:54.648769-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:32:56.447403-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 2
2019-02-03 11:32:56.447610-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:32:56.447724-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:32:56.447829-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:32:56.447931-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448151-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448281-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448389-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448490-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448589-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:32:56.448689-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:32:57.981261-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 3
2019-02-03 11:32:57.981471-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:32:57.981625-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:32:57.981745-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:32:57.981874-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982081-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982214-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982315-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982441-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982539-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:32:57.982638-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735076-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 4
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735252-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735337-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735410-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735480-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735547-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735692-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735762-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735830-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735896-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:33:00.735965-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:33:01.876340-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] Item added! pool
2019-02-03 11:33:03.352399-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 3
2019-02-03 11:33:03.352967-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:33:03.353179-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:33:03.353377-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:33:03.353569-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:33:03.353755-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:33:03.353897-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:33:03.354230-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:33:03.354612-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:33:03.354739-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:33:03.354848-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
2019-02-03 11:33:03.477654-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: 4
2019-02-03 11:33:03.477863-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Table
2019-02-03 11:33:03.477974-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Keys
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478078-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Jhghhvhh
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478178-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: Njhhnn
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478276-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] leftItem: 9th item
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478374-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Cord
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478472-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Hshhdhdbd
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478569-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Book
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478665-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: Tv
2019-02-03 11:33:03.478763-0500 HybridPool[1827:594545] rightItem: <null>
```

Answer (score 1):

Views in a tableview are reused, so everything you do to a view must also be undone. My rule is any code that touches a reuseable view cannot have an `if` without an `else`. That being said:

```
if(cell.cellLeftImageView.image == nil) {
```

is a bug.  The view will be set correctly the first time, but the second time, when the view is reused it won't be set at all.

this if:

```
if(right < [self.items count]) {
```

is also a bug.  In the case that there isn't a right item it will not set the image to nil, it will instead leave whatever image was there before.

Also having a datasource where odd and even values means something completely different is really hard to keep track of and understand.  Why are you doing it that way?  You can have objects that have `leftImageURL`, `rightImageURL`, `leftText`, `rightText`.  Part of coding is to communicate with other programmers, not to the complier.  Choosing an easier to understand data structor can go a long way to making the code do what you expect.

Next, you are using `dataWithContentsOfURL` which blocks the main thread while you are requesting the images.  I assume that this is just text code and not ever meant to used in any serious way.

Also, why are you using `valueForKey`?  What is the type of the `items`?  If they are dictionaries you can use item[@"downloadURL"], if they are some custom object you should be able to just use item.downloadURL.

Comment: i dont think being "smart" has anything to do with it, its more about how far along you are in development with what you are working on...that being said: `if(cell.cellLeftImageView.image == nil) {` makes sure that whatever row is being dequeued is empty... and `if(right < [self.items count]) {` makes sure that there is an item to be placed on the right side from the array...its really not that hard to understand why i need to do this...i could separate them into two arrays...but if i didnt do that...what would i put in this `else` condition you are speaking of?

Comment: `if(cell.cellLeftImageView.image == nil) {` is similar to `if(cell == nil)` in this case (if i wasnt putting two items in each row, which protects against the cell being reused by accident like you say....and u dont need an `else` when using `if(cell == nil)`...

Comment: if i did split them into `leftItems` and `rightItems` there would be cases where they are not even...because there is an odd number of items...understand?

Comment: also, this isnt an answer

Comment: when u say split into `leftItems` and `rightItems` do you mean to use two `UITableViews` side by side?

Comment: no, I mean two arrays. One that contains the leftImages, and one that contains the right images.  When there isn't an image for a cell you can set [NSNull null] as the value and check for that to set the image to nil.

Comment: ok...i think i see what ur saying, maybe edit your answer and add some code?

Comment: i changed it to using two separate data sources and i added the else condition but i am still getting the same result...ill post my code now

Comment: you comment about `dataWithContentsOfURL` - i just found that when researching how to add an image using a `URL`, but yes, I have noticed it blocks the main thread i just havent addressed it yet...what is the correct way?

Comment: thanks for your help i was able to figure it out with sdwebimage and using an `else` to catch the circumstance that was slipping through.

Answer (score 0):

This code provided me with the correct configuration - `leftItems` and `rightItems` are the left column and right column of the `UITableView`. If an item doesn't exist for the right side of a given row, `[NSNull null]` is passed as the object for that item (from `rightItems`):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called - row: %li", (long)indexPath.row);

    PoolsTableViewCell *cell = (PoolsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"cell == nil");
        cell = [[PoolsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSURL* leftURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.leftItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"downloadURL"]];
    [cell.cellLeftImageView sd_setImageWithURL:leftURL];
    cell.cellLeftViewLabel.text = [[self.leftItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"item"];

    if(![[self.rightItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSURL* rightURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.rightItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"downloadURL"]];
        [cell.cellRightImageView sd_setImageWithURL:rightURL];
        cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = [[self.rightItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"item"];
    }
    else {
        cell.cellRightImageView.image = nil;
        cell.cellRightViewLabel.text = @"";
    }

    return cell;
}

...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.leftItems count];
}
```